# What's Wrong with My Spring Program?

Tags: java, spring, startup

```
03-06 11:14:32.477:DEBUG DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'buildWeekTopListJob'

03-06 11:14:32.477:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Creating instance of bean 'buildWeekTopListJob'

03-06 11:14:32.478:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'buildWeekTopListJob' to allow for resolving potential circular references
03-06 11:14:32.479:DEBUG AbstractBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'guestRankService'

03-06 11:14:32.480:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'buildWeekTopListJob'

03-06 11:14:32.480:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Finished creating instance of bean 'buildWeekTopListJob'

03-06 11:14:32.481:DEBUG DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'cronDayTrigger'

03-06 11:14:32.481:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Creating instance of bean 'cronDayTrigger'

03-06 11:14:32.484:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'cronDayTrigger' to allow for resolving potential circular references
03-06 11:14:32.484:DEBUG AbstractBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'buildDayTopListJob'

**03-06 11:14:32.505:INFO DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@46c837cd: defining beans [buildDayTopListJob,famousBlogSynJob,buildWeekTopListJob,cronDayTrigger,cronWeekTrigger,cronFamousBlogSynTrigger,org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0,guestRankService,accountService]; root of factory hierarchy**
```

---

**Full Log:**

```
03-06 11:51:40.638:DEBUG ConfigUtils - Getting Config

03-06 11:51:40.643:INFO ConfigUtils - Successfully  proFileName=guestrank.properties load Properties:{log.prefix=netty-stdout.log., log.dic=/opt/logs/guest}

03-06 11:51:40.643:INFO RankServiceStart - Guest Rank Server Start -- filePrefix:netty-stdout.log.  logDic/opt/logs/guest

03-06 11:51:40.684:INFO AbstractApplicationContext - Refreshing 

org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@19b8e059: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@19b8e059]; startup date [Tue Mar 06 11:51:40 CST 2012]; root of context hierarchy

03-06 11:51:40.783:INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext-quartz.xml]

03-06 11:51:40.956:DEBUG DefaultDocumentLoader - Using JAXP provider [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]

03-06 11:51:41.221:DEBUG PluggableSchemaResolver - Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]


03-06 11:51:41.228:DEBUG PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd

03-06 11:51:41.353:DEBUG DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader - Loading bean definitions

03-06 11:51:41.381:DEBUG BeanDefinitionParserDelegate - No XML 'id' specified - using 'buildDayTopListJob' as bean name and [] as aliases

03-06 11:51:41.396:DEBUG BeanDefinitionParserDelegate - No XML 'id' specified - using 'famousBlogSynJob' as bean name and [] as aliases

03-06 11:51:41.398:DEBUG BeanDefinitionParserDelegate - No XML 'id' specified - using 'buildWeekTopListJob' as bean name and [] as aliases

03-06 11:51:41.404:DEBUG BeanDefinitionParserDelegate - Neither XML 'id' nor 'name' specified - using generated bean name [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0

03-06 11:51:41.405:DEBUG AbstractBeanDefinitionReader - Loaded 7 bean definitions from location pattern [applicationContext-quartz.xml]

03-06 11:51:41.406:INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext-service.xml]

03-06 11:51:41.409:DEBUG DefaultDocumentLoader - Using JAXP provider [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]

03-06 11:51:41.413:DEBUG PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd

03-06 11:51:41.456:DEBUG DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader - Loading bean definitions

03-06 11:51:41.458:DEBUG BeanDefinitionParserDelegate - No XML 'id' specified - using 'guestRankService' as bean name and [] as aliases

03-06 11:51:41.459:DEBUG BeanDefinitionParserDelegate - No XML 'id' specified - using 'accountService' as bean name and [] as aliases

03-06 11:51:41.460:DEBUG AbstractBeanDefinitionReader - Loaded 2 bean definitions from location pattern [applicationContext-service.xml]

03-06 11:51:41.460:INFO AbstractApplicationContext - Bean factory for application context 
[org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@19b8e059]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2c79809

03-06 11:51:41.461:DEBUG AbstractApplicationContext - 9 beans defined in org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@19b8e059: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@19b8e059]; startup date [Tue Mar 06 11:51:40 CST 2012]; root of context hierarchy

03-06 11:51:41.494:DEBUG AbstractApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@7dc05ffd]

03-06 11:51:41.497:DEBUG AbstractApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@36baa466]

03-06 11:51:41.500:DEBUG DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'guestRankService'

03-06 11:51:41.502:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Creating instance of bean 'guestRankService'

03-06 11:51:41.551:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'guestRankService' to allow for resolving potential circular references

03-06 11:51:41.585:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'guestRankService'

03-06 11:51:41.597:DEBUG ConfigCenter - getData from ConfigCenter:/suc/rmi/com.sohu.suc.guest.service.GuestRankService

03-06 11:51:41.625:INFO Environment - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.3--1, built on 07/18/2011 05:21 GMT

03-06 11:51:41.626:INFO Environment - Client environment:host.name=tc_69_108

03-06 11:51:41.627:INFO Environment - Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_25

03-06 11:51:41.627:INFO Environment - Client environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.

03-06 11:51:41.628:INFO Environment - Client environment:java.home=/opt/apps_install/jdk-1.6.0_25/jre


03-06 11:51:41.629:INFO Environment - Client environment:java.class.path=/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/bin:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/commons-collections-3.2.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/concurrent-1.3.4.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/ezmorph-1.0.4.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/ice-3.4.2.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.5.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.5.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/jedis-2.0.1.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/jta-1.1.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/junit-4.4.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/nekohtml-1.9.11.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/ojdbc-10.2.0.5.0.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/persistence-api-1.0.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/quartz-1.8.0.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/sce-proto-1.0-20111009.085518-7.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/sce-service-adapter-1.0-20120227.090915-18.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/sce-slice-1.0-20110923.100652-6.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.0.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/spring-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/spring-beans-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/spring-context-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/spring-core-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/spring-test-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/suc-account-core-0.0.1-20120221.130444-39.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/suc-base-core-0.0.1-20110929.021726-12.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/suc-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/suc-core-cache-2.0-20120117.015007-17.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/suc-dao-1.0-20111213.033026-11.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/suc-ddd-1.1-20120103.072716-2.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/suc-guest-core-0.0.1-20120224.065203-61.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/suc-profile-api-1.0-20120227.053019-56.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/suc-remote-cluster-2.0-20120105.022309-4.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/suc-utils-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/xmemcached-1.3.5.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/lib/zookeeper-3.3.3.patch.jar
03-06 11:51:41.630:INFO Environment - Client environment:java.library.path=/opt/apps_install/jdk-1.6.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/server:/opt/apps_install/jdk-1.6.0_25/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/apps_install/jdk-1.6.0_25/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib

03-06 11:51:41.630:INFO Environment - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp

03-06 11:51:41.631:INFO Environment - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>

03-06 11:51:41.632:INFO Environment - Client environment:os.name=Linux

03-06 11:51:41.632:INFO Environment - Client environment:os.arch=amd64

03-06 11:51:41.633:INFO Environment - Client environment:os.version=2.6.18-238.el5xen

03-06 11:51:41.633:INFO Environment - Client environment:user.name=root

03-06 11:51:41.634:INFO Environment - Client environment:user.home=/root

03-06 11:51:41.635:INFO Environment - Client environment:user.dir=/opt/services/suc-guest-rank/bin

03-06 11:51:41.637:INFO ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, 
connectString=zk1.in.i.sohu.com:2181,zk2.in.i.sohu.com:2181,zk3.in.i.sohu.com:2181,zk4.in.i.sohu.com:2181,zk5.in.i.sohu.com:2181/talent sessionTimeout=30000 watcher=com.sohu.suc.platform.core.zookeeper.ZookeeperClient$SucWatcher@2b5356d5

03-06 11:51:41.685:INFO ClientCnxn$SendThread - Opening socket connection to server zk5.in.i.sohu.com/10.11.156.71:2181

03-06 11:51:41.695:INFO ClientCnxn$SendThread - Socket connection established to zk5.in.i.sohu.com/10.11.156.71:2181, initiating session

03-06 11:51:41.705:INFO ClientCnxn$SendThread - Session establishment complete on server zk5.in.i.sohu.com/10.11.156.71:2181, sessionid = 0x93069ecc80f7a81, negotiated timeout = 30000

03-06 11:51:41.716:INFO ConfigCenter - check zookeeper server:true

03-06 11:51:41.716:DEBUG ConfigCenter - getDataAsString: /suc/rmi/com.sohu.suc.guest.service.GuestRankService, data=rmi://10.10.69.107:9700/GuestRankService

03-06 11:51:41.757:DEBUG JdkDynamicAopProxy - Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is EmptyTargetSource: no target class, static

03-06 11:51:41.781:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Finished creating instance of bean 'guestRankService'

03-06 11:51:41.782:DEBUG DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'accountService'

03-06 11:51:41.783:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Creating instance of bean 'accountService'

03-06 11:51:41.783:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'accountService' to allow for resolving potential circular references

03-06 11:51:41.785:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'accountService'

03-06 11:51:41.786:DEBUG ConfigCenter - getData from ConfigCenter:/suc/rmi/com.sohu.suc.account.service.AccountService

03-06 11:51:41.791:DEBUG ConfigCenter - getDataAsString: /suc/rmi/com.sohu.suc.account.service.AccountService, data=rmi://10.10.69.107:9121/AccountRMIService,rmi://10.10.69.108:9121/AccountRMIService
03-06 11:51:41.792:DEBUG JdkDynamicAopProxy - Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is EmptyTargetSource: no target class, static
03-06 11:51:41.820:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Finished creating instance of bean 'accountService'
03-06 11:51:41.820:INFO DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2c79809: defining beans [buildDayTopListJob,famousBlogSynJob,buildWeekTopListJob,cronDayTrigger,cronWeekTrigger,cronFamousBlogSynTrigger,org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0,guestRankService,accountService]; root of factory hierarchy
03-06 11:51:41.821:DEBUG DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'buildDayTopListJob'
03-06 11:51:41.821:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Creating instance of bean 'buildDayTopListJob'
03-06 11:51:41.824:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'buildDayTopListJob' to allow for resolving potential circular references
03-06 11:51:41.837:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'buildDayTopListJob'
03-06 11:51:41.838:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Finished creating instance of bean 'buildDayTopListJob'
03-06 11:51:41.839:DEBUG DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'famousBlogSynJob'
03-06 11:51:41.839:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Creating instance of bean 'famousBlogSynJob'
03-06 11:51:41.840:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'famousBlogSynJob' to allow for resolving potential circular references
03-06 11:51:41.841:DEBUG AbstractBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'accountService'
03-06 11:51:41.843:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'famousBlogSynJob'
03-06 11:51:41.844:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Finished creating instance of bean 'famousBlogSynJob'
03-06 11:51:41.845:DEBUG DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'buildWeekTopListJob'
03-06 11:51:41.845:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Creating instance of bean 'buildWeekTopListJob'
03-06 11:51:41.846:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'buildWeekTopListJob' to allow for resolving potential circular references
03-06 11:51:41.847:DEBUG AbstractBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'guestRankService'
03-06 11:51:41.847:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'buildWeekTopListJob'
03-06 11:51:41.848:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Finished creating instance of bean 'buildWeekTopListJob'
03-06 11:51:41.849:DEBUG DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'cronDayTrigger'
03-06 11:51:41.849:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1 - Creating instance of bean 'cronDayTrigger'
03-06 11:51:41.852:DEBUG AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'cronDayTrigger' to allow for resolving potential circular references
03-06 11:51:41.852:DEBUG AbstractBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'buildDayTopListJob'
03-06 11:51:41.872:INFO DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2c79809: defining beans [buildDayTopListJob,famousBlogSynJob,buildWeekTopListJob,cronDayTrigger,cronWeekTrigger,cronFamousBlogSynTrigger,org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0,guestRankService,accountService]; root of factory hierarchy
```

When I start it, it doesn't working. At the end of the log file, it has one **Destroying singletons**.  Why?

I cannot find any excepion or error in the log file.

Comment: Oh boy.... make sure if you're going to post a ton of code or info to quote, that you use the code tags or block quote tags...

Comment: finally

i found the reason

wrong config in application.xml

question：no error message ， why ？  god

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be destroying the singletons because either they are not needed or because Spring has already decided that the startup has failed.  The clues are not in that snippet of the log.

Scan back through the log for earlier ERROR entries and/or stacktraces.

---

Based on what the log says, I still say that the "Destroying singletons" message is irrelevant.  It looks like some problem in your application code that is not being logged.

(And no ... I'm NOT suggesting that you should post your code!!!)

Comment: I give you full log now，  i can`t find the ERROR entries .   this program used to analysis log ,